# Fedora version for 2.6.x kernel

Tags: kernel, fedora

Does anyone know which was Fedora's last stable release with Kernel 2.6.x. Fedora 15, Fedora 14 or Fedora 13. Fedora 16 onwards it was 3.1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fedora_releases).

Comment: Wrong place, try superuser.com

Comment: Please ask this @ http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 15 was the latest with 2.6.

Check this Wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_(operating_system)

And apparently the Fedora Project Website:

https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/kernel